# Fileendings native Apps - APPX?

Tags: shortcut, windows-10-mobile, appx

I'm writing a thesis about mobile Apps.

Now i wanted to mention the files that are required for the specific platforms.

Those are for Android, iOS, Windows 10 mobile:

APK (Android Application)

IPA (iDevice Package)

APPX ( ??? )

I could not figure out what APPX stands for and could not find any official source.

Obviously APP stand for application, but X? 
Guesses are 'Cross' as windows 10 apps are cross platform apps on Microsoft devices, or X as '10' for windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

`appx` stands for Application Package as described in the [documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx).

The x does not stand for anything and might be there just for consistency with other file formats that share a similar structure (`appx` files, same as a `docx` or `xlsx` are actually archives that contain all metadata and content as one file).

*That being said, this really isn't the right place for a question like this. It would be better suited on other StackExchange websites and your question will probably be closed very soon